# Why is gulp throwing "Did you forget to signal async completion?"

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have the following gulp file that was working fine for months until this morning:

```
//gulpfile.js
const gulp = require('gulp')
const { series } = require('gulp')
const rename = require('gulp-rename')
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'))

function minJs() {
    return gulp
        .src('./dev/js/script.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(
            rename({
                extname: '.min.js'
            })
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/js/'))
}
exports.minJs = minJs

function minCss() {
    return gulp
        .src('./dev/css/style.sass')
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(
            rename({
                extname: '.min.css'
            })
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/css/'))
}
exports.minCss = minCss

exports.test = () => {
    series(minCss, minJs)
}
```

Every time I run "Gulp test" I get the following error:

```
[11:17:59] Starting 'test'...
[11:17:59] The following tasks did not complete: test
[11:17:59] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

I've tried adding a callback to the two tasks and tried changing them to async functions but neither resolved the issue. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error since I am returning a stream.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you try `return`ing the `series` function result in `exports.test`?

Comment: Did you try `exports.test = series(minCss, minJs)`?  In my experience, this is how you use `series` -- wrapping in closures is problematic.

Comment: @edemaine Thank you! I don't know why I had it like that but it seems to be working now.

Comment: @alexyoe You're not alone -- I've made the same mistake multiple times. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[gulp.series](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/series/) is actually a higher-order rule, i.e., it makes a rule out of rules, so shouldn't be wrapped in a closure:

```js
exports.test = series(minCss, minJs);
```